# Big Numeric data types not able to import in R Studio

Tags: r, google-bigquery

I receive this error whenever i try to import a data type "Bignumeric" in R.

Error in bq_parse(fields, data) : Unknown type BIGNUMERIC

How can i fix this error so that I can import data in R from Bigquery for data classified as BigNumeric

Comment: are you using the `bigrquery` or `bigQueryR` package?

Comment: I am currently using the bigrquery